# Select a field cascading

Tags: mysql

I have a `categories` table in MySql something like this:

```
categoryId | categoryTitle | definedField | parentId
    1              Title         123           NULL
    2          AnotherTitle       234          1
    3         AndAnotherOne       NULL         1
```

What I need to do is find the closest definedField value by going up to parent,like this;

Since category 2 has a definedField, return its value;
Since category 3 does not have a definedField, search up, to its parent. It has definedField, so return it. If it didn't have one, search up until find one.

There will **ALLWAYS** be the topmost category that will have definedField set. I only need to find a good algorithm to search for this in a MySQL InnoDb table.

Comment: MySQL does not have mechanism to work with hierarchies. You could join `categories` table many-many times to find definedField, but this is not efficient. I'd do it in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way of retrieving hierarchical data in MySQL (like, for example, Postgres's RECURSIVE query).  There is a good article summarizing different ways of implementing nested data set in MySQL: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

> Most users at one time or another have dealt with hierarchical data in
>   a SQL database and no doubt learned that the management of
>   hierarchical data is not what a relational database is intended for.
>   The tables of a relational database are not hierarchical (like XML),
>   but are simply a flat list. Hierarchical data has a parent-child
>   relationship that is not naturally represented in a relational
>   database table.

The article covers two models: Adjacency List and Nested Set.

**The Adjacency List Model**

> In the adjacency list model, each item in the table contains a pointer
>   to its parent. The topmost element, in this case electronics, has a
>   NULL value for its parent. The adjacency list model has the advantage
>   of being quite simple, it is easy to see thatFLASH is a child ofmp3
>   players, which is a child of portable electronics, which is a child of
>   electronics. While the adjacency list model can be dealt with fairly
>   easily in client-side code, working with the model can be more
>   problematic in pure SQL.

**The Nested Set Model**

> In the Nested Set Model, we can look at our hierarchy in a new way,
>   not as nodes and lines, but as nested containers.

Comment: Hmm. That means, that I am probably going to have to find a way to find this data and cache it for further use. Thanks!